# Insert update in multiple tables in edmx files when table have relationship

Tags: .net

How can I insert  and update data in mutiple tables when tables have the base derived relation ship  in database through entity framework modal (.edmx )

I am trying with below code but its not working .

```
public bool FacilityRegistrationVerification(FacilityRegistration oFacilityRegisteration)
        {       
            {
                using (levytaxEntities context = new levytaxEntities())
                {
                    var cast = context.FacilityRegistrations.Where(x => x.FacilityID == oFacilityRegisteration.FacilityID).Single();
                    cast = oFacilityRegisteration;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose u have two tables `Movies` & `Cast` (the pictures of both these tables are given below) ---> 
[image]
[image]

and now u want to access data of Cast using MovieId (**Cast.MovieId is FK of Movies_tbl.id**)
than the Linq will be--->

```
private static void ShowCast(MoviesEntities moviesEntities)
        {
            using (moviesEntities)
            {
                ShowAllMovies(moviesEntities);

                Console.WriteLine("Movie id");
                var id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                using (var mEntities = new MoviesEntities())
                {
                    if (mEntities.Movies_tbl.Any(x => x.id == id))
                    {
                        var Actor = mEntities.Movies_tbl.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id).Cast.Actor;
                        Console.WriteLine(Actor);

                        var Actoress = mEntities.Movies_tbl.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id).Cast.Actoress;
                        Console.WriteLine(Actoress);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


private static void ShowAllMovies(MoviesEntities moviesEntities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("movies ids");

            using (moviesEntities)
            {
                var idList = moviesEntities.Movies_tbl.Select(x => x.id);

                foreach (var idin idList )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(id.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

**TO ADD AN OBJECT (insert a record into database)**--->

```
private static void AddMovie(MoviesEntities moviesEntities)
        {
            using (moviesEntities)
            {
                moviesEntities.Movies_tbl.AddObject(new Movies_tbl { title = "ExampleTitle", Cast = new Cast { Actor = "ExampleActor", Actoress = "ExampleActoress" } });
                moviesEntities.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

**TO UPDATE AN OBJECT (perform update operation into the database)**--->

```
private static void UpdateCast(MoviesEntities moviesEntities)
        {
            using (moviesEntities)
            {
                var cast = moviesEntities.Casts.Where(x => x.MovieId == 10).Single();
                cast.Actor = "UpdatedActorName";
                cast.Actoress = "UpdatedActoressName";
                moviesEntities.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

where `MoviesEntities` is the **partial class with suffix ‘entities’ and derived from ObjectContext class.**

it will be automatically created when u will create the `.edmx` by existing database

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to insert or  update table by entity framework .I get the object of derived class which have the data of derives and base class and now i want to insert or update these both table ..sohow can i do this ..

Comment: public bool FacilityRegistrationVerification(FacilityRegistration oFacilityRegisteration)
        {       
            {
                using (levytaxEntities context = new levytaxEntities())
                {
                    var cast = context.FacilityRegistrations.Where(x => x.FacilityID == oFacilityRegisteration.FacilityID).Single();
                    cast = oFacilityRegisteration;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
           }
        }

Comment: unable to mark ur reply as a answer as points are less than 15 .pls see above code and let me know whts the wrong with this one

Comment: first format the code befor pasting here, so it could be able to understand. & in ur code, the method not returning value (bool type). except this ur code seems fine.